# Actionbar disable left and right blank

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have tried add a custom view into support actionbar.it showed [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iALCG.png)

And my code is here ,

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar);

    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

How can i disable left and right black blank ?
Thanks.

Comment: It might be the padding you given in your actionbar custom  layout.

Comment: my xml is here <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/action_bar_root"
    android:gravity="fill_horizontal">

Comment: To be honest with you, there is no need for the Actionbar. Just get rid of it and use a layout.  Make your life a whole lot easier